# Angular Material Expansion Panels: How to expand initially, but then let the user expand/collapse as they please

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an expansion panel that contains a list of data. When the component loads, I want the panel to be expanded if the length of its data is 0, and collapsed if the length of its data is more than 0.

After initializing, I want the panel to only expand or collapse if the user clicks on it. So if the length of the panel's data changes from 0 to 1, I don't want the panel to then collapse, I want it to stay open.
The problem is that when I use the expansion panel's [expanded] input, it keeps checking the condition, so when the length of the data changes it expands or collapses even if the user didn't click on it.

```
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="!item.data.length">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
      Item with data
    </mat-panel-title>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <div *ngFor="let data of item.data">
    {{data.name}}
  </div>
  <button (click)="addDataToItem()">ADD DATA</button>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

**Desired results:** The expansion panel is initially expanded if `item.data.length` is 0, and initially collapsed if `item.data.length` is more than 0. Then, if the user clicks the ADD DATA button, the expansion panel stays opened.

**Actual results:** The expansion panel is initially expanded if the `item.data.length` is 0, and collapsed if it is more than 0. But if the user clicks ADD DATA, the

panel closes because the length is more than 0.

Here is a an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lhvysp) of the behavior.

Notice how the panel is initially expanded because the length is 0, but then when you click ADD DATA, it collapses because the length is 1. I would like it to stay open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a boolean in the Component and set it to item.data.length === 0 and just check that in the template.

```
public expanded: boolean = this.item.data.length === 0;

<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="expanded">
```

edit: messed up the link

https://angular-esfqzh.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

`<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="!item.data.length">`

to:

`<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="item.data.length">`

Comment: That doesn't work because he wants the panel closed if the data is not empty at the beginning.